# Django auth model: combine multiple fields into one username_field

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have multiple fields users have to specify on signup: `date_of_birth, first_name, last_name`.

What I now want is to combine these fields to one for USERNAME_FIELD, like so:
`John_Doe_01011988`

The following obviously doesn't work:

```
USERNAME_FIELD='%s-%s' % ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date_of_birth is a datetime you could transform it into a string and append all the strings together like so :

```
import datetime

first_name = 'John'
last_name = 'Doe'
date_of_birth = datetime.datetime(1988, 1, 1)

str_dob = str(date_of_birth).split(' ')[0].replace('-', '')
username = "{}_{}_{}".format(first_name,last_name, str_dob)
```

Out :

```
'John_Doe_19880101'
```